# Is it possible to declare in the same XML file , the same field , in a different table ?

Tags: xml, dtd

Given the DTD file below :

```
!ELEMENT hotels (address+)>
<!ELEMENT address (city,street,phone,hotelDetails)>
<!ELEMENT hotelDetails (hotel_code,hotel_rank,hotel_name)>
<!ELEMENT street (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT city (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT hotel_rank (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT phone (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT hotel_code (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT hotel_name (#PCDATA)>

<!ELEMENT guests (id+)>
<!ELEMENT guestDetails (name,city,address,state)>
<!ELEMENT name (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT city (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT address (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT state (#PCDATA)>
```

As you can see, I have two different tables : `hotels` & `guests` , where both tables 
has a column of `city` . When I try to save the file in `XMLspy` I get  :

```
Element 'city' has already been declared.
```

Is there a way to declare that field for both tables ?

Regards

Ron

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need this element only once. It may be referenced from both address and guestDetails.